# Draw and clear brush on picturebox image c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I have winform project in c#. There is a Picturebox on the form and Checkboxes around this Picturebox.

I want to draw line to appear on which side the user checked the checkbox. And i want the line to be deleted when the user unchecks the checkbox. I explained in the picture below.

[image]

I tried the codes below. It is not working.

**Edit:** Many thanx for Marco and TaW. I tried the method they suggested in the comments and it worked perfectly.

**Edit2:** Based on Flydog57 & Jimi's valuable notices, the codes have been revised.Thanx.

I am sharing the codes below for those who have similar request.

```
 private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
   using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            if (chc_left.Checked)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, pictureBox3.Height));
            if (chc_top.Checked)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox3.Width, 10));
            if (chc_bottom.Checked)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, pictureBox3.Height - 10, pictureBox3.Width, 10));
            if (chc_right.Checked)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(pictureBox3.Width - 10, 0, 10, pictureBox3.Height));
        }
   }

    // this event should be applied for all checkboxes.
  private void chc_left_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      pictureBox3.Invalidate(); 
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use `new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height)` instead? just guessing (I can't try it right now)...

Comment: @Marco i tried yours but it is not work. The problem is i do not know when the paint event is triggered except form loading.

Comment: yes, Marco is right; as the Paint is drawing onto the PBox the coordinates are relative to it. The Paint event gets triggered when the system needs to and also when you call pbox.Invalidate, which you need to do in the checkbox checkchanged event. You will also need to set the coordinates inside the if clause(s) as the other four will need different values..

Comment: As @TaW told you, you should catch the checked change event of every checkbox and call `pictureBox3.Invalidate(); pictureBox3.Refresh();`

Comment: No need for a Refresh, really. Also: he really can use the same checked/checkchanged event for all checkboxes..

Comment: @TaW: sure, he can use a single method for the 4 checkboxes! For the Refresh I'm not sure at the moment, but I trust you completely :)

Comment: What you are missing is disposing of the brush you create in the Paint handler: `using var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);`.  Otherwise, what you have should work

Comment: If you always use the same Brush, you can declare it as a Field instead of creating (and of course disposing, as mentioned) a new one each time the Control is invalidated. -- This line: `Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;` has no use at all. I'd understand if you had written, e.g., `var g = e.Graphics;`, in case you're *lazy*, so you can write `g.FillRectangle(...)` instead of `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(...)`. This is the only use for this assignment. I'm saying this because I see this thing in code snippets found here and there; something that has the cargo cult vibe.

Comment: @Jimi Microsoft likes to do that in their examples, [Managing the State of a Graphics Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/managing-the-state-of-a-graphics-object?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @LarsTech I know :) Fortunately, all more recent updates to the Docs (the one you linked is more than 10 years old) use `e.Graphics` instead.